# Image.thumbnail - can't change size properly

Tags: django, image, thumbnails

I am trying to create model for news. My model contains ImageField where i wont to store thumbnail:

```
class News(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(verbose_name=u'tytuł', max_length=40)
    lead = models.TextField(verbose_name=u'zajawka', blank= False)
    body = models.TextField(verbose_name=u'treść ogłosznia', blank=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    active = models.BooleanField(verbose_name=u'aktywność ogłoszenia')
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name=u'data publikacji')
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    lead_photo= models.ImageField(upload_to="lead_photo/")
    objects= NewsManager()
```

I found on the other site code and i modified it to my needs:

```
def save(self, force_update=False, force_insert=False, thumb_size=(120,120)):
    from PIL import Image
    from cStringIO import StringIO
    from django.core.files.uploadedfile import SimpleUploadedFile
    image = Image.open(self.lead_photo)

    if image.mode not in ('L', 'RGB'):
        image = image.convert('RGB')

    image.thumbnail(thumb_size, Image.ANTIALIAS)

    # save the thumbnail to memory
    temp_handle = StringIO()
    image.save(temp_handle, 'JPEG')
    temp_handle.seek(0) # rewind the file

    # save to the thumbnail field
    suf = SimpleUploadedFile(os.path.split(self.lead_photo.name)[-1],
                             temp_handle.read(),
                             content_type='image/jpeg')
    self.lead_photo.save(suf.name+'.png', suf, save=False)

    # save the image object
    super(News, self).save(force_update, force_insert)
```

the problem is that i cant create thumbnail with different width and height proportion. When for instance a set thumb_size(240,320) i'll get the same proportion as in oryginal but picture is smaller. Thanks for advices.

Edit:
On PIL documentation i found very interesting sentence about that method:
"This method modifies the image to contain a thumbnail version of itself, no larger than the given size." So is there any option to make it exact that size?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [`resize`](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html?highlight=resize#PIL.Image.Image.resize) method.

And as a variant you can create new background image ([doc](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html?highlight=resize#PIL.Image.new)):

```
newImage = Image.new(resized.mode, resized.size, "black")
```

and place your main image on it keeping aspect ratio resized by  `image.thumbnail(thumb_size, Image.ANTIALIAS)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:
http://djangothumbnails.com/

```
from django.db import models
from thumbs import ImageWithThumbsField

class Person(models.Model):
    photo = ImageWithThumbsField(upload_to='images', sizes=((125,125),(200,200)))
```

Do not forget intall pillow

```
pip install pillow
```